# Is possible to access a remote JMS embedded queue?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I have a embedded ActiveMQ instance in my Spring Boot app and I would like to consume a queue on that instance, from another processes or machine.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is definitely possible given the proper broker configuration. It just needs connectors that are bound to network interfaces visible from remote clients.

Comment: The broker URL used is vm://embedded?broker.persistent=true. Should I use de default port (61616) to connect?

Comment: Not without adding a tcp transport with that port to the broker configuration first.

Comment: And how to do it?